# log4j2 RollingFile Error renaming file

Tags: java, log4j2, rollingfileappender

I have this appender

```
 <RollingFile name="Application" fileName="/home/user/log/abc.log" filePattern="/var/log/mylog/abc-%d{yyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} abc        %-10level %class{36} %L %M - %msg%xEx%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 MB" />
            </Policies>
                <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="9999"/>
    </RollingFile>
```

when the 5 MB are reached and there is no space on /var/log/mylog I get the error `"ERROR renaming file from xx to yy` If I make space afterwards, the logger does not try again to rename the file. Any ideas how I could solve that?

I use log4j2 2.2

Comment: Wild suggestion: make sure you always have enough space. Having less than 5MB of free space is not a good thing for any filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. I don't have enough reputation to make a comment.

SUGGESTION: Log4j2 allows you to automatically delete files older then X days. I've been struggling with this some time ago. The issue has been resolved here:

[Log4j2 - Configure RolloverStrategy to delete old log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741262/log4j2-configure-rolloverstrategy-to-delete-old-log-files)

Maybe this will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you configure a FailoverAppender and put your RollingFileAppender within it then you can configure the FailoverAppender to retry at an interval you configure. In the meantime, the log events can be routed to a secondary appender that can do something else.  See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#FailoverAppender.

Comment: this is not working for me, maybe the problem is because the rollingfile appender itself does not fail, because this is logging in a tmpfs where still enough space is available, but if the 5mb are exceeded and there is not enought space /var/log/mylog/, the failover appender does not try it again+

Comment: Make sure you have the rolling file appender configured with ignoreExceptions="false"

Answer (score 0):

try removing ":" here {yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}
something like below

```
<PatternLayout>
       <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd} abc        %-10level %class{36} %L %M - %msg%xEx%n</Pattern>
</PatternLayout>
```