# limiting maximum number of rolled up log files in log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am using log4j2 to provision logging in my code.
I am using the time based trigger policy.
However the delete is not working for me and I am getting the following error

```
016-08-05 14:44:22,635 main ERROR appender RollingFile has no parameter that matches element Delete
2016-08-05 14:44:22.686 [WARN ] [main] Class1 - new cycle
2016-08-05 14:44:22.691 [DEBUG] [main] Class1 - Hello this is a debug message
2016-08-05 14:44:22.691 [INFO ] [main] Class1 - Hello this is an info message
2016-08-05 14:44:22.692 [FATAL] [main] Class1 - Beaware This is a Fatal message
2016-08-05 14:44:22.692 [ERROR] [main] Class1 - This is an error message
2016-08-05 14:44:22.692 [INFO ] [main] Class2 - In constructor of class2
2016-08-05 14:44:22.692 [INFO ] [main] Class1 - Repeating cycle
2016-08-05 14:44:22.692 [DEBUG] [main] Class1 - Hello this is a debug message
2016-08-05 14:44:22.692 [INFO ] [main] Class1 - Hello this is an info message
2016-08-05 14:44:22.693 [FATAL] [main] Class1 - Beaware This is a Fatal message
2016-08-05 14:44:22.693 [ERROR] [main] Class1 - This is an error message
```

Below is my log4j2 config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">D:/logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console-log" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="file-log" fileName="${log-path}/custom-log.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/customelog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
            <Delete basePath="${log-path}" maxDepth="2">
                <IfFileName glob="customelog-*.log" />
                <IfLastModified age="1m" />
            </Delete>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="test.Class1" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="file-log" level="debug" />
            <appender-ref ref="console-log" level="debug" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="all" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console-log" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

My test code is below

class1.java:

```
package test;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Class1 {
    public static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Class1.class);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        logger.warn("new cycle");
        logger.debug("Hello this is a debug message");
        logger.info("Hello this is an info message");
        logger.fatal("Beaware This is a Fatal message");
        logger.error("This is an error message");

        Class2 obj = new Class2();

        logger.info("Repeating cycle");
        logger.debug("Hello this is a debug message");
        logger.info("Hello this is an info message");
        logger.fatal("Beaware This is a Fatal message");
        logger.error("This is an error message");
    }
}
```

Class2.java

```
package test;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Class2 {
    public static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Class2.class);
    public Class2(){
        Class2.logger.info("In constructor of class2");
    }

}
```

The problem is the error stated above and the fact that the files are not getting deleted if there age is more than 1 minute

Can you please let me know what mistake I am making because of which my delete functionality is not working?

I have used the following example here [Log4j2 - Configure RolloverStrategy to delete old log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741262/log4j2-configure-rolloverstrategy-to-delete-old-log-files)

Thanks,

Vikas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `Delete` tag should be wrapped in a `DefaultRolloverStrategy`

e.g.

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="D:/app.log"
                     filePattern="D:/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="60" modulate="true"/>
                <!--<SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>-->
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
                <Delete basePath="D:" maxDepth="1">
                    <IfFileName glob="app-*.log" />
                    <IfLastModified age="3m" />
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
```

Comment: Thanks @Scary Wombat, I just figured out the same!!