# log4j2 unable to delete old files

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have searched everywhere for the answer. I have to delete files after the number of file archived is more than 10.

This is my log4j2.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="C:/temp/logs/app.log"
            filePattern="C:/temp/logs/app.log.%i">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1000 kb" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10">
                <Delete basePath="C:/temp/logs/" maxDepth="1">
                    <IfFileName glob="app*.log*">
                        <IfLastModified age="2m">
                            <IfAny>
                                <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="11" />
                            </IfAny>
                        </IfLastModified>
                    </IfFileName>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

But it does not delete all the files in the folder. For example in the screenshot below, it does not delete the old log file:

[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCtBz.jpg)

I have gone through all the documentation and lots of discussions but I couldn't solve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar question to one asked and might provide some help on what you are trying to do = [Log4j2 - Configure RolloverStrategy to delete old log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741262/log4j2-configure-rolloverstrategy-to-delete-old-log-files).

The comments should explain what each condition under Delete would do. In your example, if you like app-log-12-20* to be deleted, then you need to either remove either the IfLastModified or IfAccumulatedFileCount  - you will see the file getting deleted

```
 <Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="C:/temp/logs/app.log"
        filePattern="C:/temp/logs/app.log.%i">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1000 kb" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10">
            <Delete basePath="C:/temp/logs/" maxDepth="1">
                <IfAll> 

                    <!-- Looks for file names starting with app*.log*. Any file including app.log.1 will satisfy this condition. Could delete current log app.log -->
                    <IfFileName glob="app*.log*" />
                    <!-- Looks for files that are older than 2 mins --> 
                    <IfLastModified age="2m" />  
                     <!-- This means there need to be 11 fails that satisfy the above conditions, that i.e. their name is app*log* and have time stamp greater than 2 mins. Keeps the most recent files that satisfy the condition -->
                    <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="11" /> 
                </IfAll>
            </Delete>
        </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Comment: Thank you Saifuddin Merchant but the logs are supposed to be deleted if it is more than 2 minutes old or the file count reaches 10, whichever comes first. But even though I remove <IfLastModified> or <IfAccumulatedFileCount>, it still wont delete the older files. There are 16 app*.log* files, 2 new rest are old files (6 days old). It should not be more than 10 files at a given time(if I remove the <IfLastmodified>). However, it works if I manually delete the old files, but if I need to put the code in production, that is not an option to delete older log files.